# Calculate TIME IN ACCESS more than 24hours

Tags: sql, ms-access, time

I don't know if it's the right place to ask my question but I can't find anything else related in  the Website.

I have an Access database that creates reports.

I have create queries and I want to calculate time more than 24 hours. 
I have use function

```
TimeSerial((Sum(Minute(Table1.Field1)+Hour(Table1.Field1)*60)\60),(Sum(Minute(Table1.Field1)+Hour(Table1.Field1)*60) Mod 60),0) AS test
```

but the problem is that when the hours is more than 24 start from the beginning.

For example if I have a sum of 27:30 hours the result from my query will be 
3:30.

Comment: Please give us some sample data and the expected output. `TimeSerial` is not the function to calculate time difference. It will just "convert" (hour, minute, seconds) to XX:XX:XX am/pm. So if it is more than 24 hours, it will just find out the time corresponding to that 24 hours ago.

Comment: For example  I wan to calculate the time that an employee works a month.

Comment: The expected output will be  Name  Total Hours of Month

Comment: Kostas   works      160:50

Comment: Is this clear or need more?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATEDIFF` function:

Example:

```
DATEDIFF("h", start_date, end_date)
```

More info here: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php

Comment: How can calculate with datediff when I don't have start_date and end_date. I have one field which shows the daily hours for the user tat works. This field repeated every day * x days that has a month. I want the specific field to calculate and create a new field with the total hours.

Comment: Your question is not even clear. You did not tell us what you have and what you expect to see in the output. Please post your sample data.

Comment: Then just simply use `SUM` of all fields. Why bother with the `TimeSerial`?

Comment: Sorry but I can't post images

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @d1 DATETIME
DECLARE @d2 DATETIME
SET @d1 = '6/1/2014 12:15'
SET @d2 = '6/5/2014 18:22'
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, @d1, @d2)
SELECT CAST((DATEDIFF(minute, @d1, @d2) / 60) AS VARCHAR(8)) + ':' +
       right('0' + CAST((DATEDIFF(minute, @d1, @d2) % 60) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

Comment: The OP doesn't even know what he is asking. Read what he commented in my answer.

Comment: I try and I will inform for my results

Comment: It says ms access, not sql server in the tags.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found the solution and now it's working without prolem